# Applying array size restriction to aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

This should be simple but can't work it out. My schema is as follows:

[image]

I have this query which is retrieving the average of `$reviews.rating` rounded to 2 decimals (working)

```
db.films.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{title:1, reviewavg:{$round:[{$avg:"$reviews.rating"},2] }}
    }
])
```

I now want to extend it to retrieve the rating averages only for films that have 3 or more reviews. This is what I came up with (I put in a `match` clause trying to restrict on the size of the `reviews` array where its greater than or equal to 3):

```
db.films.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            {$size:"$reviews"}:{$gte:3}
        },
        $project:
        {
            title:1, 
            reviewavg:
            {
                $round:[{$avg:"$reviews.rating"},2] 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

It's not working but can't figure it out. Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: What part isn't working? What are you getting and what are you expecting? mongoplayground links are always appreciated

Comment: @user20042973 the first query is working. The second query `$match:` clause isn't working. I'm not even sure if this logic belong in the `match` clause. The error I'm getting in MongoDB Compass: Error: `clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.`

Comment: @user20042973 mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pFnuu72fYwc

Comment: wrap the `$gte` in `$expr` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mqx9dyy1n1c)